# Creating Lists based on some criteria in Java

Tags: list, java-7

I have following data in a table. And I want to make `List<String>` objects based on the batch ID. Same batch ID customers will be in a List. Batch Id is sequential, sorted and unique. With following data I will have 3 Lists. What would be the efficient way in Java 7? (I can not use Java 8)

```
Customer        Batch ID
-------------------------
Alex            1
Brad            1
Erin            1   
John            2
Grace           3
Olivia          3
```

List1 = {Alex, Brad, Erin}
List2 = {John}
List3 = {Grace, Olivia}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it *have* to be Java 7? This is simple in Java 8.

Assuming for a moment your input data is a list of Person, where batch ID is a property*:

```
Map<Integer, List<Person>> byBatchId = people
    .stream()
    .collect(groupingBy(Person::getBatchId));
```

And then you can extract the lists by the batch id.

*if the data isn't already in that form, then you can start by converting it to that form :)

In pure Java 7, a simple way would be by building a `Map` manually. This doesn't take advantage of the sorted sequential nature, but is still nice and efficient. Note: here be mutations.

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> byBatchId = new HashMap<>();
for(Person person : people) {
    // initialise the list if it doesn't already exist
    Integer batchId = person.batchId();
    if(!byBatchId.containsKey(batchId) {
        byBatchId.put(batchId, new ArrayList<>());
    }
    // then it's safe to add to the list
    byBatchId.get(batchId).add(person);
}
```

Comment: I have already data in that form. But my server does not have Java 8. I just need in Java 7. I have made the edit in the question.